# Read only file system, which allows also temporary write to other destination

Tags: filesystems, mount, storage

Is there any file system which allows reading from an existing network share, but also writing to the "mount", but those writes are only temporary?

To let you know the background: We have around 4TB data on our live system. If we want to test our staging system, the stage should be able to access the data, but not modify it. Nevertheless the stage needs write permission, but all the changes stage is causing should be written to some temporary space, which will not affect live system.

I want to avoid to clone 4TB data all the time.

Comment: "If we want to test our staging system, the stage should be able to access the data, but not modify it. Nevertheless the stage needs write permission[...]" Why does it need write permission?

Comment: Because integration tests on stage also rely on write function. Like testing upload forms, and so on

Answer (score 3):

An overlay filesystem seems to be exactly what you need:  Mount your data as read only, create a temporary filesystem (tmpfs) and then overlay those two. Writes then only go to the temporary filesystem.

Examples of such filesystems are [UnionFS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) and [OverlayFS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS).

Answer (score 1):

[BTRFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) with a snapshot to the state you want preserved.